# How to create a time lapse video like the photos app?

Tags: ios, photo, video-capture, cmsamplebufferref, timelapse

I'm looking for a way to create long time lapse videos on an iPhone running iOS 9, and hoping to get some pointers on how to start. Ideally I would compress 1 hour of footage into 1 minute, so the scaling factor is 60. I take one frame out of 60 and stitch them together, right?

I have a project which uses AVFoundation capture images using `captureOutput:idOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`

However, **I'm not sure if there are better approaches to creating a time lapse over several hours**.

- Would it make sense to take individual photos and stitch them together (activating camera every few seconds)?
- Or just take frames out of CMSampleBufferRef?
- Are there other APIs I can use for capturing camera images?

  I'm hoping to understand which approach would result in the highest quality and battery life.

[I'm looking at this question which appears to have code for stitching images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136633/avfoundation-retiming-cmsamplebufferref-video-output), but I'm not sure if I need anything else for my project.

Comment: AVAssetWriterInput will be your best friend : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriterInput_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAssetWriterInput/appendSampleBuffer:

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish *timelapse* would be , instead of using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`  to process video frames , you can use `AVCapturePhotoOutput` to get the images from the sample buffers.

A timer is then set to Capture the sampleBuffer every second or so , and finally you stitch the frames together with `AVAssetWriter` to have the video.

Checkout Apple's StopNGo sample app.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider how dslr captures it you will get the hold of it.

The camera basically clicks 1 picture after every n seconds.

Let's say you set the value to 60. This will result into 1 click every minute. You leave the camera for 8 hours -> 480 minutes -> 480 pictures.

Now its time to stitch these frames together. Lets say you add them with 10 fps , meaning 10 pics in 1 second. This will result in 48 seconds of total footage. I wrote a short piece on this. If needed I can provide the link.